# How I can consider Van der Waals interactions between two materials in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: quantum-espresso, dispersion-correction

I'm working on a **hybrid system (with two different materials)**. Could you tell me how I can take into consideration the **Van der Waals interaction** between them?

Comment: I don't use QE, but it looks like the necessary input tags can be found here (quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html) if you go to the page and CTRL + F for "Van der Waals correction".

Comment: you can consider that by using this vdw_corr = 'grimme-d2', !taking vdw interaction correction

Comment: @ahmed hassan
thank you for your answer
why exactly 'grimme-d2' and not
and not "grimme-d3" or 'DFT-D'......

Comment: It depends on your work what do you want to study

Comment: If you have experimental structure information (lattice constants and angles for example), one way is to just try a few vdW corrections and see which agrees more with experiments. Otherwise, you could try to find some kind of benchmark study to justify why you pick a particular vdW correction or functional.

Comment: Please have a look at the expected behaviour regarding greetings such as good morning , thanks, sorry on the expected behaviour of MMSE [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). I have edited the question to remove them since the expected behaviour is to not include them in questions.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been almost 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know! Were the comments here helpful?